# Jstree Valid_children between multiple trees

Tags: jquery, types, jstree

I currently have 2 jstrees both using the Types plugin in to define each node with a type.  My problem is that when I drag one node from jstree #1, with type "Topic" to another tree jstree #2 with a node of type "Folder" it just gives me a red X.  I have type "Folder" defined with **"valid_children": "Topic"** on jstree #2

jstree #1 Toolbox.  Used to drag certain nodes into the other Node.  "Always_copy"

```
.jstree({
    "core": {
        //Prevent node from being deleted when moved to the design tree
        "check_callback": function (operation, node, node_parent, node_position, more) {

        },
        "data": {
            "url": getToolTreeUrl,
            "data": function (node) {
                return { 'id': node.id };
            }
        }
    },
    //Enabled the drag and drop plugin with ability to drag and drop between tree
    "plugins": ["dnd", "unique", "types", "ccrm"],
    "crrm": {
        "move": {
            "check_copy": function () {
                alert("Check_Copy");
            },
        },
    },
    "types": {
        "#": {
            "max_children": 1,
            "max_depth": 2
        },
        "Topic": {
            "valid_children": "Task"
        },
        "Task": {
            "valid_children": "Task"
        },
        "Paragraph": {

        },
        "Dictionary_List": {

        },
        "Ordered_List": {

        },
        "Unordered_List": {

        },
        "List_Item": {

        },
        "Picture": {

        },
        "Video": {

        },
        "Table": {

        },
        "Note": {

        },
        "QHSE-Note": {

        },
    },
    "dnd": {
        always_copy: true,
        is_draggable: function (data) {
            return data[0].id != 0; //disallow entire toolbox being dragged
        },
    },
    rules: {
        multitree: true,
        draggable: "all"
    }
});
```

}

jstree #2 is my Document that receives nodes from the toolbox.

```
.jstree({
    "core": {
        "check_callback": function (operation, node, node_parent, node_position, more) {
            var type = node.text;
            var parentValue = node.parent;

            if (operation == "move_node") {
                asyncPost(getObjectLogicCheckUrl);
            }
            if (operation == "copy_node") {
                asyncPost(getObjectLogicCheckUrl);
            }
        },
        "data": data
    },
    "plugins": ["dnd", "contextmenu", "types"], contextmenu: { items: customMenu },
    "crrm": {
        "move": {
            "check_copy": function () {
                alert("Check_Copy");
            },
        },  
    },
    "types": {
        "#": {
            "max_children": 1
       },
       "Topic": {
           //"valid_children": "Task"
       },
       "Task": {
           //"valid_children": ["Task", "Paragraph", "Dictionary_List", "Ordered_List", "Unordered_List", "Picture", "Video", "Table", "Note", "QHSE-Note"],
       },
       "Paragraph": {
           //"valid_children": ["Paragraph", "Dictionary_List", "Ordered_List", "Unordered_List", "Picture", "Video", "Table", "Note", "QHSE-Note"]
       },
       "Dictionary_List": {
           "valid_children": ["List_Item"]
       },
       "Ordered_List": {
           "valid_children": ["List_Item"]
       },
       "Unordered_List": {
           "valid_children": ["List_Item"]
       },
       "List_Item": {
           "max_children": 0
       },
       "Picture": {
           "max_children": 0
       },
       "Video": {
           "max_children": 0
       },
       "Table": {
           "max_children": 0
       },
       "Note": {

       },
       "QHSE-Note": {

       },
       "Folder": {
           "valid_children": "Topic"
       },
    },
    rules: {
        multitree: true,
        draggable: "all",
    },
```

I am trying to figure out a way to lock down which nodes can be dragged where in the Documents Tree.  IE..  a node with type "Topic" can only accept a node with type "Task".

If anyone knows how to enable the Types plugin to work between multiple trees, please help.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.  Both Tree Nodes need to have the same rules applied for it to work.

jstree #1

```
"Topic": {
       "valid_children": "Task"
   },
```

jstree #2

```
"Topic": {
       "valid_children": "Task"
   },
```